# Ejecutar otro jar en el programa java

Tags: java, jar

Tengo unos archivos a.jar b.jar y main.jar

Nesecito que main.jar los ejecute y además los archivos tengan acceso a algunos paquetes del Main, ¿ES Eso posible?.

```
class Main{
   public static void exeJar(String g){
      
   }
   public static void Main(String[] arg){
     exeJar("a.jar");
   }
}
```

Comment: Necesita detalles o aclaraciones. Esta pregunta debería incluir más detalles para aclarar el problema. Por ejemplo la versión de java, la estructura de paquetes, que error te produce tu código, con que versiones del jdk fueron compilados tus jars y a que nivel de clase, con que versión de java piensas correrlos, etc

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente, no se "ejecutas otros archivos jar", los agregas a tu classpath y usas su código en tu aplicación, ¿puedes hacerlo así? Si puede, después de agregarlos a la classpath, dentro de su clase realiza importaciones y usa lo que necesite dentro de su método main, como si fuera su propio código.

```
import java.util.Random; //<-- esso no es mio, esta en un otro jar, eso jar esta em mi classpath e puedo importar sus classes aqui

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Despues de importar, puedo usar el codigo como se fuera mio
    Random RAND = new Random();
    int i = RAND.nextInt();
    
}
```

Si no puede poseer, agregar a classpath o incluso saber cuáles son esos jar, puede usar `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar a.jar")` para ejecutar cosas externas, también puede usar un `ProcessBuilder`, que me gusta más, ejemplo de código con esto a bajo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    execProcess("a.jar");
}

private static synchronized String execProcess(final String args) {
    try {
        final Process p = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "java", "-jar", args).start();
        final InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
        final InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        
        String line = "";
        final StringBuilder scOutput = new StringBuilder();
        
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            scOutput.append(line);
        }
        
        return scOutput.toString();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}
```